# My reputation decreased but no record of it, perhaps a bug with documentation

Tags: bug, documentation

My reputation doesn't change much. Since documentation went live, I've been getting huge amounts of reputation for a small edit I made on CSS background color a long time ago. Yesterday it was over 900 (I don't remember exactly), but today it is 887 and it doesn't show any reputation decreases or that it ever was over 900. I suspect this could be related to the documentation going live in some way. Yes I'm fairly confident I'm not going crazy.

I'm not concerned about the reputation but thought I'd report this as a potential bug.